# Receiving 400 - Mail service not enabled when calling Gmail API

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api

I am using OAuth 2.0 Client ID while working with Gmail API.

For one customer when calling `gmail_v1.Gmail.users.messages.list({userId: 'me'})` endpoint (or any other endpoint), I am receiving a "Mail service not enabled" 400 error without any further explanation of what happened. Gmail API documentation does not include such an error definition.

The customer has access to Gmail. The email they are trying to connect is part of another Google organisation. Other customers inside and outside our Google organisation can use the endpoint successfully.

Full response from Gmail API:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Mail service not enabled",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Mail service not enabled",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "failedPrecondition"
            }
        ],
        "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a setting in their Google admin organisation which could enable Gmail API?

Comment: Does this issue happen specifically for that user? Also just wanted to verify as well if the Google Workspace account experiencing the error was just recently established / created?

Answer (score 1):

This error normally only comes if your trial service has expired.

Have your workspace admin check the account and ensure that you have billing enabled and that the trial time hasn't just expired.